# Not able to fetch role assignments of an item in a list via SharePoint rest APIs

Tags: sharepoint, azure-active-directory

I am using azure AD credentials(username, password, client id and client secret) to create access token. I am able to fetch all the data from SharePoint except ACLs/ Role Assignments using SharePoint rest APIs. Need to know what permission is required in Azure to fetch ACL data from SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with permission. With AllSites.FullControl permission, I was able to retrieve data.